# Armstrong numbers in base 90

Tags: elementary-number-theory, recreational-mathematics

Are there any Armstrong numbers (narcissistic numbers) in base 90?  Of course, except the one-digit ones.  There don't seem to be.  Just curious.

Comment: Why base 90? (Just curious here as well)

Comment: It is the first one with neither 2-digit nor 3-digit Armstrong numbers, or 4-digit ones if I wrote the program correctly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try $~\{73\}\{62\}\{15\}\{62\}\{83\}\{18\}\{39\}\{47\}.\quad$ See [link](http://www.deimel.org/rec_math/dik1.htm).